# Exception: Cannot invoke getLastRowNum()" as "sheet" is null

Tags: selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, testng, java-19

I'm getting the following exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.getLastRowNum()" as "sheet" is null

```
public static Object[][] getTestDataFromExcel(String sheetName) {
    File excelFile = new File("C:\\Users\\abhis\\seleniumHybridFramework\\seleniumHybridFramework\\src\\main\\java\\com\\seleniumHybridFrameworkProject\\qa\\testdata\\seleniumHybridFrameworkProjectTestData.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fisExcel = new FileInputStream(excelFile);
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fisExcel);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);

    int rows = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    int cols = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();

    Object[][] data1 = new Object[rows][cols];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i + 1);
        
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
            CellType cellType = cell.getCellType();

            switch (cellType) {
                case STRING:
                    data1[i][j] = cell.getStringCellValue();
                    break;
                case NUMERIC:
                    data1[i][j] = Integer.toString((int) cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    break;
                case BOOLEAN:
                    data1[i][j] = cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                    break;
            }

        }

    }
    return data1;
}
```

Here in `XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName)`,
`getSheet` is underlined and showing suggestion that this can produce `Nullpointer Exception` becoz sheet may be is `null`.

I have poi version 5.2.2
poi-ooxml version 5.2.2
poi-ooxml-schemas 4.1.0

I don't know why it is not recognizing the sheet in a sheet path and workbook is `null`.

I have tried `File excelFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\main\\java\\com\\seleniumHybridFrameworkProject\\qa\\testdata\\seleniumHybridFrameworkProjectTestData.xlsx")`.

Please look at it.

Answer (score 2):

The error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.getLastRowNum()" as "sheet" is null
```

tells that `sheet` is `null`.

That's possible because [XSSFWorkbook.getSheet](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#getSheet-java.lang.String-) either returns the
`XSSFSheet` with the name provided or `null` if it does not exist. So in your code after `XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);` `sheet` might be null if there is not a sheet having name given in `sheetName` in the workbook.

As always for `NullPointerException` you have to check whether you got an object and not `null`.

```
...
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
if (sheet != null) { 
 int rows = sheet.getLastRowNum();
 //... do what to do with sheet
}
...
```

Btw.: `poi-ooxml-schemas 4.1.0` does not fit to `poi-ooxml` version `5.2.2` as mixing Apache POI versions is not supported and will lead to unexpected errors. See [faq-N10204](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10204).

See [Apache POI - Component Overview](https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html). The `poi-ooxml` of version `5.2.2` needs either `poi-ooxml-lite` of same version `5.2.2` or `poi-ooxml-full` of same version `5.2.2` but nothing of version `4.1.0`.